# How to test php api stored in webmin file storage?

Tags: php, webmin

I'm currently building a flutter web application and developing some php API.
For practical reasons, I tested these APIs on a local server (XAMPP), but now I have access to a webmin server that has file storage.

How can I store such APIs in that storage and what path should I provide to my source code to access the APIs?

For example, this was the path that i gave when the APIs where in my own local server:

```dart
const String apiUrl = "http://localhost:8000/sd/api/";
```

Sorry for my ignorance, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: learn how to use [Apache](https://www.guru99.com/apache.html), also learn [MVC](https://www.giuseppemaccario.com/how-to-build-a-simple-php-mvc-framework/) (Model-View-Controller) instead of a view, just return json data instead of html.

Comment: Well, replace localhost with the domain or IP address of the new server. As for the folder, we don't know how your server is configured so it's difficult to be specific

Comment: @ADyson im not the owner of the server, i only know that i've a folder in the file storage to put all the project files. I was wondering if you know which path, in general, should i use

Comment: It's possible to configure each server differently. If you've been given a folder to put the files in then I suggest using that. Then try to use use the host name/ IP as the URL and see what happens. Contact the server administrator if you are still unsure